# Kotlin Retrofit response.body() returned null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

So I'm trying to fetch an API with endpoint `https://someURL.com/someUrl/url?orderID=A001`,

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA6st.png) is the returned JSON format as seen from Postman.
So I use this Interface in the `NetworkConfig.kt` class to fetch this endpoint:

```
interface getOutstandingOrderDetail{
    @GET("url")
    fun getOutstandingOrderDetail(@Query("orderID") orderID: String): Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData>
}
```

and store it in this data class (Generated by an Android Extension that generate POJO from JSON):

```
data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass(

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("error")
    val error: Error? = null
)

data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData(

    @field:SerializedName("Header")
    val header: OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassHeader? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("Detail")
    val detail: List<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem?>? = null
)

data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassHeader(

    @field:SerializedName("buyer_address")
    val buyerAddress: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price")
    val totalPrice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("buyer_name")
    val buyerName: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_confirmed_yn")
    val statusConfirmedYn: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_date")
    val orderDate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("outlet_id")
    val outletId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("nip")
    val nip: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("jumlah_product")
    val jumlahProduct: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("last_update")
    val lastUpdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("phone_number")
    val phoneNumber: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_running_id")
    val orderRunningId: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_tagged_yn")
    val statusTaggedYn: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_id")
    val orderId: String? = null
)

data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassError(

    @field:SerializedName("msg")
    val msg: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("code")
    val code: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status")
    val status: Boolean? = null
)
data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem(

    @field:SerializedName("item_price_new")
    val itemPriceNew: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_name_new")
    val itemNameNew: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price")
    val totalPrice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_price")
    val itemPrice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_name")
    val itemName: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_refund")
    val statusRefund: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("detail_id")
    val detailId: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("procode_new")
    val procodeNew: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("refund_date")
    val refundDate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("request_refund")
    val requestRefund: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("procode")
    val procode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("last_update")
    val lastUpdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_qty_new")
    val itemQtyNew: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_id")
    val orderId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price_new")
    val totalPriceNew: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_qty")
    val itemQty: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("refund")
    val refund: Int? = null
)
```

This is a code snippet of the fragment where I fetch the URL data:

```
private fun fetchOrderedItemListData() {
    NetworkConfig()
        .getOutstandingDetailOrderedItemListService()
        .getOutstandingOrderDetailOrderedItemList("A001")
        .enqueue(object :
            Callback<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData> {

            override fun onFailure(
                call: Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData>,
                t: Throwable
            ) {
                Log.i("Order", "It Failed!!")

                if (call.isCanceled) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        (activity as AppCompatActivity),
                        "Request Aborted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        (activity as AppCompatActivity),
                        t.localizedMessage,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData>,
                response: Response<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData>
            ) {

                Log.i("Order", "Ordered Item FEtched -> \n ${response.body()}") <= This is for debugging purpose

                binding.rvOrderedItemList.adapter =
                    response.body()
                        ?.let { OrderedItemListAdapter(it, this@OrderDetailFragment) }

                binding.rvOrderedItemList.layoutManager =
                    LinearLayoutManager((activity as AppCompatActivity))

            }
        })
}
```

As you can see above I use Log.i to try to print the response.body() in the LogCat, However it returns null in the Log Cat. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEfXy.png).

Am I missing something ? If there's any detail that I left out for this question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you share the response of the API that you got from the postman? I can't really verify by just seeing your POJO class.

Comment: The one from postman ? I already attach it to a hyperlink above. Just before the interface snippet

Comment: "However it returns null in the Log Cat" -- not according to the screenshot. `body()` is returning a `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData`. The `header` and `detail` properties of the `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData` are `null`. This indicates that your JSON did not match your classes. Perhaps your Retrofit function should be returning a `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass` instead of a `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData`, as that would better match your JSON.

Comment: so i cannot directly access `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData` or something ? Never mind dude. Your solution worked. Thanks !! You should write the answer so it can help another user in the future.

Comment: Note that you need to use `@` notation to have your comments be directed to somebody's inbox. By default, comments here only go to your inbox (except for your own comments, which go to nobody's inbox). The only reason why I saw your comment is because I specifically returned to this question to check on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Retrofit function is set up as:

```kotlin
    @GET("switch")
    fun getOutstandingOrderDetail(@Query("orderID") orderID: String): Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData>
```

The data type in the `Call<>` needs to match your JSON. You have data classes that match your JSON... but the root of that hierarchy is `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass`, not `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData`. So, change your Retrofit function to:

```kotlin
    @GET("switch")
    fun getOutstandingOrderDetail(@Query("orderID") orderID: String): Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass>
```

Comment: Since the body may be null due to unexpected backend changes, and we don't want the app to crash with NPE, should we declare our `Call` with a nullable version of our model response?

Comment: @JCarlosR: I suppose you could try that. I do not think that `null` will be parsed as JSON, and I would expect you to get some sort of an exception rather than a `null` response, at least by default. You might be able to create a Retrofit plugin that changes that behavior.